# How would you write a T-SQL query that supported event study analysis

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I trying to create a table that will support a simple event study analysis, but I'm not sure how best to approach this.

I'd like to create a table with the following columns: Customer, Date, Time on website, Outcome. I'm testing the premise that the outcome for a particular customer on any give day if a function of the time spent on the website on the current day as well as the preceding five site visits. I'm envisioning a table similar to this:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ98l.png]

I'm hoping to write a T-SQL query that will produce an output like this:

[image]

Given this objective, here are my questions:

- Assuming this is indeed possible, how should I structure my table to accomplish this objective? Is there a need for a column that refers to the prior visit? Do I need to add an index to a particular column?
- Would this be considered a recursive query?
- Given the appropriate table structure, what would the query look like?
- Is it possible to structure the query with a variable that determines the number of prior periods to include in addition to the current period (for example, if I want to compare 5 periods to 3 periods)?

Comment: I have counted 6 questions here...Too much. And I wonder how you determine exact time on site in seconds?

Comment: I believe the seconds are determined from log files.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand analytic value of your matrix

```
Declare @Table table (id int,VisitDate date,VisitTime int,Outcome varchar(25))
Insert Into @Table (id,VisitDate,VisitTime,Outcome) values
(123,'2015-12-01',100,'P'),
(123,'2016-01-01',101,'P'),
(123,'2016-02-01',102,'N'),
(123,'2016-03-01',100,'P'),
(123,'2016-04-01', 99,'N'),
(123,'2016-04-09', 98,'P'),
(123,'2016-05-09', 99,'P'),
(123,'2016-05-14',100,'N'),
(123,'2016-06-13', 99,'P'),
(123,'2016-06-15', 98,'P')

Select *
      ,T0 = VisitTime
      ,T1 = Lead(VisitTime,1,0) over(Partition By ID Order By ID,VisitDate Desc)
      ,T2 = Lead(VisitTime,2,0) over(Partition By ID Order By ID,VisitDate Desc)
      ,T3 = Lead(VisitTime,3,0) over(Partition By ID Order By ID,VisitDate Desc)
      ,T4 = Lead(VisitTime,4,0) over(Partition By ID Order By ID,VisitDate Desc)
      ,T5 = Lead(VisitTime,5,0) over(Partition By ID Order By ID,VisitDate Desc)
 From @Table 
 Order By ID,VisitDate Desc
```

Returns

```
id  VisitDate   VisitTime   Outcome T0  T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
123 2016-06-15  98          P       98  99  100 99  98  99
123 2016-06-13  99          P       99  100 99  98  99  100
123 2016-05-14  100         N       100 99  98  99  100 102
123 2016-05-09  99          P       99  98  99  100 102 101
123 2016-04-09  98          P       98  99  100 102 101 100
123 2016-04-01  99          N       99  100 102 101 100 0
123 2016-03-01  100         P       100 102 101 100 0   0
123 2016-02-01  102         N       102 101 100 0   0   0
123 2016-01-01  101         P       101 100 0   0   0   0
123 2015-12-01  100         P       100 0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

With fixed columns you can do it like this with lag:

```
select
  time,
  lag(time, 1) over (partition by customer order by date desc), 
  lag(time, 2) over (partition by customer order by date desc), 
  lag(time, 3) over (partition by customer order by date desc), 
  lag(time, 4) over (partition by customer order by date desc)
from
  yourtable
```

If you need dynamic columns, then you'll have to build it using dynamic SQL.